# NUXT | Как выполнить действие при запуске ЛЮБОЙ страницы?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, hook, ssr

Нужно  взять token из localStorage и засунуть его в store.
Пытался делать через nuxtServerInit, но эта функция выполняется на сервере, где нет localStorage.
Есть ли какие-нибудь хуки для всего проекта Nuxt?

Comment: При запуске любой страницы или при переходе по любой страницы внутри (которые без перезагрузки)?

Comment: При запуске любой страницы. Ну вот пользователь открыл сайт, и на какой странице бы он ни был, нужно получить его токен из localStorage, чтобы затем получить по этому токену его данные с сервера. Мог бы засунуть присваивание токена во всей layouts, но, как мне кажется, это неправильно

Answer (score 0):

Давайте определимся для начала, что Вы патаетесь сделать. Скорее всего Вы уже записали в localStorage, он уже там есть. Дальше Вы пытаетесь к каждой ссылке притянуть токен. Нет никакой необходимости каждый раз его подтягивать, а можно использовать axios interceptors ([пример реализации](https://github.com/ErriourRU/Nuxt-starter-pack/blob/main/plugins/axios.js), [документация](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)).

Дальше, если Вы хотите что-то при запуске делать в приложении, просто создаете плагин и в файле `nuxt.config.js` в секции `plugins` его регистрируете. Тогда при первом запуске код будет отрабатывать ([пример заполнения данных пользователя в localStorage](https://github.com/ErriourRU/Nuxt-starter-pack/blob/main/plugins/init.js)). На стороне сервера, правильно заметили, нужно тоже подтягивать данные в localStorage (да, на сервере он тоже есть, и его нужно заполнять, чтобы не получить рассинхрона, иначе зачем вообще Nuxt использовать).

---

Момент, который не относится к вопросу: не храните в локальном хранилище токен. Во-первых, его придется брать для серверного localStorage, что сделать будет невозможно из клиентсвкого. Во-вторых, срок жизни задать тут невозможно. Используйте куки, там этих проблем не будет.

Comment: Куки тоже не видит :<

Comment: @bourbaki Должно видеть. Посмотрите примеры из бандла, который я у себя использую, там точно всё работает как надо.